# Getting error in spring config file error : The value of attribute "xmlns" associated with an element type "beans" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: xml

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
>       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
>   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
>          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
>          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
>
> ```
> <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as
>     beans -->
> <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />
>
> <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
> <mvc:annotation-driven />
>
> <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
> <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
>
> <!-- View Resolver -->
> <bean id="viewResolver"
>     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>     <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
>     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
> </bean>
> <bean id="messageSource"
>     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
>     <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
> </bean>
> </beans>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the beginning of the xml file.  Should look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as
    beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
</bean>
</beans>
```